# Getting dynamic IP although specified a static one

Tags: linux, dhcp, wireless-access-point, static-ip

I have a Linux machine on raspberry that function as an access point.

```
Linux raspberrypi 3.18.7-v7+ #755 SMP PREEMPT Thu Feb 12 17:20:48 GMT 2015 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

And I have a DHCP server on it. in the /etc/network/interfaces I've defined a static IP address however whenever I start it I get an IP which is not the static one but rather from the DHCP server. This behavior is not consistent and sometimes I get the static IP.

this is a module as part of a project that function sometimes as an AP and sometimes as Client based on parameters in a script. some of the cases when changing back to AP it gets the IP wrong although the conf files are as below in all cases.

this is my hostapd.conf

```
interface=wlan0    
driver=rtl871xdrv    
ssid=my ssid
hw_mode=g
channel=6
auth_algs=1
ieee80211n=1
```

this is my interfaces file

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
  address 192.168.0.1
  netmask 255.255.255.0
```

dhcpd.conf

```
ddns-update-style none;
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
authoritative;
log-facility local7;
subnet 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range  192.168.0.10 192.168.0.50;
  option broadcast-address 192.168.0.255;
  option routers 192.168.0.1;
  default-lease-time 600;
  max-lease-time 7200;
  option domain-name "domain";
}
```

ifconfig wlan0

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 74:da:38:26:9f:d6
          inet addr:192.168.0.33  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:129 errors:0 dropped:5369 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:726 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:65760423 (62.7 MiB)  TX bytes:12737873 (12.1 MiB)
```

ifquery wlan0

```
address: 192.168.0.1
netmask: 255.255.255.0
broadcast: 192.168.0.255
```

ping to 192.168.0.1 was changed to 192.168.0.33 and got destination unreachable
ping to 192.168.0.33 works

the eth0 didn't get an IP.

Comment: Please add the output of `ip addr` (or `ifconfig`).

Comment: I've added the ifconfig data.

Comment: also this behavior is not consistent, sometimes I do get the static ip - added to the question body.

Comment: "I have a Linux machine" - which distribution? Do you have network-manager service running or a similar service that is doing some auto configuration.

Comment: it runs on a raspberry - added uname -a

Comment: Unfortunately, `uname` doesn’t show the distribution. But judging from the config format, it’s either Debian or a Debian-based.

Comment: you're right, its Raspbian which is Debian based.

Comment: For it to act as an access point, then the wlan and wired LAN must be bridged. If the wlan and wired LAN are bridged then they cannot have separate IP addresses. I don't see any configuration for the bridged interface, so how are you bridging the two?

Comment: He could always host some services directly on the Pi. In general, there’s of course no need for bridging at all. That’s only necessary when extending a wired network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a race condition between the DHCP client and the "AP mode". meaning that I got an IP from my own DHCP.

I fixed it by providing the static IP I wanted, to the DHCP server with a constraint to limit it to my MAC Address only.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your eth0 and wlan0 are on different IP address ranges, and that your DHCP server only listens on the wlan0 device. Also, make sure that it doesn't contain a leased address for the wlan0 MAC address.

Then, make sure that no other services touching wlan0 are active (I am thinking of NetworkManager, wicd and similar services). Also, you need to somehow guarantee that, when switching from "Client Mode" to "AP Mode", no race conditions can happen. Otherwise, a stray DHCP client from the client mode may decide to change the IP address back.

Comment: the wlan0 get a leased address, this is the root of the problem but I've specified an explicit static IP address in the interfaces file. how can I prevent it from happening?